# How pull changes from github to bitbucket after initial import?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, pull, git-pull

When I first created my new repository at bitbucket I used the option of importing source from github (Import existing code). However that git repo has now updated and I would like to pull those changes and update my repo at bitbucket too. How can I do that?

Answer (score 34):

You need to:

- clone your BitBucket repo locally
- add a remote referencing your GitHub repo

  ```
  git remote add github /url/of/github/repo
  ```
- pull from that github repo

  ```
  git pull github master
  ```
- push back to bitbucket

  ```
  git push -u origin master
  ```

Comment: Works like charm!
@C graphics, this should be marked as anwser!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I have deleted the old repository from bitbucket and than i could reclone it/import it from github to bitbucket.

Simple like that.

Comment: This would mean you would lose any changes you had made at bitbucket

Comment: that is correct! ii had all my info into git and created a bit account, just because i can hAve the code in private, without having to pay a fee.